# How do I access unresponsive pages in MarkLogic Admin on port 8001?

Tags: marklogic

Last week I installed MarkLogic 8.0 for macOS, and I was able to configure the databases using the Admin application service, no problems. This week however, many pages on port 8001 are unresponsive, but not all: `/license.xqy` is working fine.

Nothing special can found in `ErrorLog.txt`, and in `8001_AccessLog.txt` the unresponsive URLs don't show up. Before starting MarkLogic port 8001 is not in use.

I've reinstalled MarkLogic, but that didn't help. I didn't remove all the databases I had set up, that would be very inconvenient.

What could possibly be the reason that some page, among which `http://localhost:8001/`, are entirely unresponsive, while others work fine?

Comment: Could you give an example of which pages?

Comment: If installing ML8 was an upgrade, MarkLogic probably needed to update the database indexes. Has the sluggishness remained a problem, or did it clear up?

Comment: Try checking http://localhost:8002/dashboard/. Any indications that MarkLogic is working on something (or anything else suspicious)?

Comment: @DaveCassel Indeed the dashboard shows that query execution for `/` is still running ever since I opened `http://localhost:8001/`. Installation was no upgrade, it was a clean install. 
@DavidEnnis Unresponsive pages include `/database-admin.xqy` and `/http-server-admin.xqy`.

Comment: Do you have a Support contract? If so, I think this is worth a ticket.

Comment: Is the Management API responsive? Try getting [group properties](http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/groups/Default/properties). If that works, use [PUT to the same endpoint](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/groups/[id-or-name]/properties) to set the logging level to "debug".

Comment: You didn't remove all databases, so technically this is not a clean install. Do other app servers work? Can you use [Configuration Manager](http://localhost:8002/nav/?type=databases) to capture configuration and MLCP to export the data? If so, consider moving ~/Library/Application\ Support/MarkLogic/Data/ elsewhere, then reinstalling, then restoring content (a bit drastic, but ought to work). My thought: you didn't remove all databases, so this isn't technically a clean install. Something in the config may be hosed.

Comment: I said it was a clean install at the moment the problem occurred. I've moved the `Data/` folder away and reconfigured MarkLogic, now the problem is gone. I tested swapping the old and new `Data` folder, and then the problem is back. So clearly the problem is in the `Data` folder. Anyway, I resorted to starting from scratch again, to not loose to much time over this glitch.

Answer (score 1):

Various thoughts jump to mind, but mostly guesses:

- Did you check cpu load? MarkLogic could be busy with merges, which can make MarkLogic sluggish. Merges appear in the ErrorLog by the way.
- Did you check memory load? MarkLogic might be competing with other processes for resources, and causing processes to get pushing into swap space.
- Did you run OS updates, or did they run automatically? Not sure how that could affect MarkLogic, just trying to establish if anything changed.
- Did you check disk space? Maybe you are running low on free space, and some filesystems get considerably slower when going under a certain amount or percentage of free space.
- Do you have databases with CPF enabled? There is a trigger to relaunch CPF at restart.

I think I did observe this a few times on a local vm, but afraid I forgot the details..

HTH!

Comment: CPU load is 5%, 8GB of free memory (MarkLogic has been using between 350MB and 900MB), no available OS updates, computer is idle, 300GB free disk space, not using CPF.

Comment: Are the pages on 8001 just very slow, or does the browser give an error message? See if you can reach http://localhost:8001/cluster-status.xqy?more=more, and check for anomalies. Sure ErrorLog.txt doesn't report anything, no abnormal activities?

Comment: The pages that do load are fast as usual, the unresponsive pages transmit 0 bytes and do not close the connection after the browser closes the page. Even after MarkLogic is shut down the port isn't immediately cleaned up, it remains under `netstat` as `TIME_WAIT` for some time. The cluster status shows nothing unusual, but the page does work. `ErrorrLog.txt` shows only `Notice` and `Info` lines.